# What Javascript / jQuery pattern is this to enclosing and hiding everything but still can alter the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Did somebody come up with this pattern so it is a famous and well-known pattern?
I see this pattern for using Javascript / jQuery, such as in `init.js`:

```
var Initializations = {};

Initializations = (function($) {

  function doSomething(i, domElement) { 
    // ... 
  }

  $(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function() {
      // ...
    });
    $(".bar").each(doSomething);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

So it looks like it can "hide" almost everything from the global scope, avoid conflict if another library also uses `$` as a variable, and the HTML page can be altered by this code using jQuery.  The code does almost nothing to the global scope (except the variable `Initializations`), and even if there are
2 jQuery versions, and if they can be denoted by 2 variables `jQuery142` and `jQuery161`, then the code can be even using 2 jQuery libraries just by changing the last line of the code above
to `jQuery161` (say, if some 3rd party code needs jQuery 1.4.2 and your code has been using jQuery 1.6.1 for new features and/or bug fixes).

Can the above code be improved?  I am wondering why the extra variable `Initializations`, why not just:

```
(function($) {

  function doSomething(i, domElement) { 
    // ... 
  }

  $(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function() {
      // ...
    });
    $(".bar").each(doSomething);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Crockford's pattern and the Revealing Module Pattern](http://www.alexanderdickson.com/articles/jquery-javascript/a-new-way-of-creating-objects-in-javascript/). They are similar to what you posted but go a bit further and show why you'd want to namespace with the Initializations var.

Comment: but `Initializations` is never used -- it is not to create this object, but just to hide everything.  So is not using any variable good or is there any motivation to add a variable?

Comment: You asked about patterns, so I posted info regarding patterns that are similar to the code you posted. It seems like you're asking about how to hide vars from global scope in a block of code that you want to execute immediately and only once. In that case, you can do what you did in your second example. That is a feature of JavaScript called a self executing anonymous function. It is not a pattern. There are OOP patterns based on self executing anonymous functions, but that is just a feature of the language itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it works, go with it.

Personally, I think that you are looking WAY to deep into the code snippet you just posted. Its a fairly standard technique in Javascript.

Comment: standard technique in jQuery or Javascript?  If Javascript (not jQuery), how is it like?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($, undefined) {

  function Something(i, domElement) { 
    // ... 
  }

  Something.prototype.doSomething = ...

  var something = new Something(10, $("#foo")[0]);
  something.doSomething();

});
```

Yes it can be improved. Your example is a start. I recommend you also add a bit of OOP into the mix.

Comment: what is the 10, and your initial code seems to have removed the loop `each`?

Comment: @CantSpellYourName :(. Yes It's just a generic mockup. You can get the constructor to do anything you want. You can make 2, 5, 20 constructors each controlling a specific piece of functionality on your page.

Comment: have you forgotten copy and paste?